# Converting a multi-page pdf to multiple JPG images with Imagick and PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have a small script for creating jpg images from an uploaded multi-paged pdf file ($uploadfile) with Imagick:

```
$imagick = new imagick();
$imagick->setResolution(600, 600);
$imagick->readImage($uploadfile);
$imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
$pages = (int)$imagick->getNumberImages();
foreach($imagick as $i=>$imagick) {
    $imagick->writeImage($uploadfile. " page ". ($i+1) ." of ".  $pages.".jpg");
}
$imagick->clear();
unlink ($uploadfile);
```

This works fine for a 1 or 2 paged pdf-document, but gives an error with **3 or more** pages:

```
[lsapi:error] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Failed to read the file' in /index.php:152\nStack trace:\n#0 /index.php(152): Imagick->readimage('...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /index.php on line 152\n
```

Line 152 mentioned in the error log is:

```
$imagick->readImage($uploadfile);
```

---

#### Solved.

It was a memory problem. I changed the code to:

```
$im = new imagick($uploadfile);
$pages = $im->getNumberImages();
if ($pages < 3) { $resolution = 600; } else { $resolution = floor(sqrt(1000000/$pages)); }
$imagick = new imagick();
$imagick->setResolution($resolution, $resolution);
$imagick->readImage($uploadfile);
$imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
foreach($imagick as $i=>$imagick) { $imagick->writeImage($uploadfile. " page ". ($i+1) ." of ".  $pages.".jpg"); }
$imagick->clear();
```

And now it works great!

Comment: I just tried your code with a 5 page PDF and it worked. Have you tried it with longer PDF from different sources? Are you sure the file is actually where you think it is?

Comment: This will be a PHP file upload permissions issue....you need to check that apache is creating the files with permissions that PHP can read.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check the size of the pdf files, perhaps, it exceeds "memory_limit" setting in php.ini